# JavaScript compiler error in Google tag manager

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Maybe some JS expert could help me to fix / modify this script ?!

```
<script type=”application/javascript”>
var gclid_field = document.querySelector(“#gclid_field”);
gclid_field.value={{Store GA ID}};
</script>
```

Many thanks,

Comment: These type of quotes come when you copy paste stuff from forums that don't format their code right. `”application/javascript”` should be `"application/javascript"`

Comment: @FUZIION you've missed the `“#gclid_field”` part.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your code editor is not quite a code editor. Replace `”` with `"`